# Ruby on Rails stubbing method when working on the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an action that contains the following call:

```
parser = Parser.new(open(@urlsearch.url))
```

The problem is that this is an expensive call and also relies on me having internet connectivity.

When I am running this from a functional test, I can stub this call using mocha but I want to stub this when I am working on the view.  I do not want to have to wait for this call to execute when refreshing the page while working on the UI.

Can anyone suggest a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

my first reaction is to simply wrap that with an if statement:

```
if Rails.env == "development"
  parser = Parser.new(open(@urlsearch.url))
else
  parser = #do your stub
end
```